# How to remove title bar which appears along with print dialog

Tags: macos, printing

I have an OpenGL fullscreen Mac OS app. It's `window` is created with `NSBorderlessWindowMask` style:

```
NSWindow *window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:rect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:YES];
```

I need to print from the app.

My printing code looks this:

```
NSPrintInfo *printInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
printInfo.orientation = NSPaperOrientationLandscape;
printInfo.verticalPagination = NSFitPagination;
printInfo.horizontalPagination = NSFitPagination;
printInfo.topMargin = 0;
printInfo.bottomMargin = 0;
printInfo.leftMargin = 0;
printInfo.rightMargin = 0;
[printInfo setHorizontallyCentered:YES];
[printInfo setVerticallyCentered:NO];
NSPrintOperation *op = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:printingView printInfo:printInfo];
[printingView release];

[op runOperationModalForWindow:self.window delegate:self didRunSelector:@selector(printOperationDidRun:success:contextInfo:) contextInfo:nil];
```

[image]

Printing dialog appears along with a titlebar:

[image]

That's not good that titlebar appears, but acceptable.

If I select "print" or "cancel", the dialog and the titlebar both disappear.

But if I select printing to PDF, titlebar remains and cannot be removed at all:

[image]

How do I get rid of the title bar?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it'd be more natural for the print panel to come up as a separate modal window rather than a sheet from an invisible window, and maybe it won't cause menu bar problems.
I believe NSPrintOperation's `runOperation` uses a modal window (and also blocks until it's complete), have you tried that?